# Firewall Security Issue

Tags: windows-server-2008, ip, windows-firewall

I'm running a few servers off Windows Server 2008, although I have some problems with client connections. To troubleshoot the issue I have clients ping an IP that is behind a router, and they are able to ping successfully. Although when pinging an IP behind the Windows Firewall Security on the server, they are unable to. Is this an issue with an option not being enabled via "Windows Firewall Security"?... This only happens to a very small group of users, but this is only the ones that I know of whom connect to my IPs. Open to any questions anyone may have to explain my situation further.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going to **Windows Firewall with Advance Security** on the server, going to **Inbound Rules** and enable **File and printer sharing (Echo Request ipv4)** on all profiles